# I have a recipe that calls for 5 leaves of tarragon, how much dried should I use?

Tags: spices

I have a recipe that calls for 5 leaves of tarragon, how much dried tarragon should I use?

Comment: What is the recipe? five leaves of fresh tarragon isn't a lot... how is it used?

Comment: It's for a marsala sauce over pork

Comment: Your title and question seem to be opposite.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule when substituting dried herbs for fresh herbs is to use a third of the amount (because it shrinks and becomes concentrated). However, tarragon doesn't shrink when it is dried and your recipe only calls for 5 fresh leaves, so I would say just use 5 dried leaves.